# What is the replacement of pdflush in linux kernel 4.14 version

Tags: linux

pdflush (linux 2.6 version) for flushing buffer cache . But what is the replacement in 4.14 kernel version?

Comment: [linux kernel - Can't find the pdflush thread? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/328609/cant-find-the-pdflush-thread)

Comment: [Does the pdflush mechanism still hold? | Linux.com | The source for Linux information](https://www.linux.com/forums/kernel-development/does-pdflush-mechanism-still-hold)